# Use a generated column in MariaDB 5.5.52

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a valid sql statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='monatlich' THEN betrag*12 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='vierteljährlich' THEN betrag*4 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='halbjährlich' THEN betrag*2 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='jährlich' THEN betrag END) as total FROM banking
```

Now I want to create a generated column which does exactly the same. I tried this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `banking` ADD `test` DECIMAL(10,2) AS (SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='monatlich' THEN betrag*12 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='vierteljährlich' THEN betrag*4 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='halbjährlich' THEN betrag*2 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN faell_art='jährlich' THEN betrag END)) AFTER `kommentar`;
```

However it doesn´t work ("#1901 - Function or expression is not allowed for column 'test'").

Any help? Thx :-)

Comment: SUM() seems suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limitation:

> subqueries or anything that depends on data outside the row are not
>   allowed (these are not deterministic because the underlying data can
>   change).

All aggregate functions (SUM,...) operate with other records in the table.

[Virtual (Computed) Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/).

So, that generated column cannot be created. Or, you could create a view.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/ - so if I upgrade to MariaDB 10.2.1 it would work? ("Virtual columns could only use deterministic functions. Since MariaDB 10.2.1 this limitation applies only to PERSISTENT columns.")

Comment: After reading the documentation I think that we have not deterministic situation. But your notice is quite interesting notice, it should be checked.

Comment: So I´ve got a MariaDB 10.2.5 instance and now I get the following error: "MySQL said:
#1901 - Function or expression 'sum()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `test`"